# Visual Studio 2010 Data Compare Automation

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, compare

I noticed in premium edition Data menu with Data Compare option which does everything I need. Just wondering whether there is a way to automate what's done in GUI  from my application. 
Ideally I'd like to get collections of different/left/right rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this blog I’ll lead you through the various parameters for the “Data.NewDataComparison” ...

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psirr/data-compare-dte-commands)

Answer (score 1):

Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx) with VSDBCMD.EXE. Then see [Schema Compare DTE Commands](http://blogs.msdn.com/psirr/archive/2008/11/22/schema-compare-dte-commands.aspx).

I suspect **something like**

```
devenv /Command Data.NewSchemaComparison [/ProviderType ConnectionBased | ProjectBased | FileBased] [/ConnectionString connection] | [/DatabaseName databaseName] | [/ConnectionName name] | [ProjectName proj] | [/FileName fileName] [/DspFamily family][ProviderType ConnectionBased | ProjectBased | FileBased] [/ConnectionString connection] | [/DatabaseName databaseName] | [/ConnectionName name] | [ProjectName proj] | [/FileName fileName] [/DspFamily family]
```

I'm hoping that there is a similar command for Data Compare.

Comment: I am primarily interested in Data not Schema comparison.