# Visual Studio 2017 Data Comparison, command line

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, data-comparison

I'm using this function in Visual Studio to easily sync data from one database to another

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833428(v=vs.100).aspx

You can save the Data Compare settings into a .dcmp file.  Everytime I open the .dcmp file, it runs a comparison and I can press the update button to write data to DEV.

But how can I run this automatically? Is there a command line to run the .dcmp file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Visual Studio 2017**

There is the **Tools.NewDataComparison** command.

**Visual Studio 2012-2015 (?)**

You have the **Sql.NewDataComparison** command.
Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn266028.aspx).

**Visual Studio 2010**

You have the **Data.NewDataComparison** command, run it from devenv.
Create a batch file if you need to automate this.
More on NewDataComparison command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779538/visual-studio-2010-data-compare-automation) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470565(v=vs.100).aspx#CompareData).

Comment: Yea I saw those.  Those links are 7 years old for version 2010.

Comment: Note: added 2017 info. Yes, they renamed it again.